# How to calculate arithmetic mean roughness Ra using ImageJ instead of MountiansMap software?

Tags: imagej

How to calculate arithmetic mean roughness Ra using ImageJ instead of MountiansMap software?
MountiansMap has a 3 days trial limition, I have the STL 3D data, how to use this data in ImageJ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt8ou.png)

calculate a real roughness Ra value with stl 3D data in ImageJ.

Comment: This is a rather special question that requires that a possibly responding person is familiar with MountainsMap® and the STL data format (CAD). <https://www.digitalsurf.com/software-solutions/profilometry/> (BTW, the trial period is 30 days!) I don't think that there are too many around here who can help. I wish you good luck. Here is one of many posts dealing with ImageJ and surface roughness: <https://forum.image.sc/t/surface-roughness-measurement/40406>

Comment: @Herbie MountainsMap 10.1 default installation is 3 days trial, after approval by digitalsurf.com headquarter will get 30 days trial(not easy). All papers and videos are about 3D roughness: 1.) Surface roughness From SEM image using image J( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQQsuGKdKpw&ab_channel=Prof.ManoharZate)
2.) Measuring Surface Roughness Using Confocal Microscopy and ImageJ (or Fiji variant).pdf. Is there any other software that can analyse 3D STL surface roughness?

Comment: Isn't surface roughness essentially 3D?
Usually one starts with images where the gray-values stand for heights. If you convert your data to such images, you may use ImageJ for roughness analyses.

Comment: @Herbie I inspect a small stent with a Super-high magnification lens zoom 3D microscope, and I get a 3D stl file, not a gray-values image. MountiansMap can analysis it directly but it is only 3 days trial.

Comment: As I wrote, for ImageJ you would need images where the gray-values stand for heights. If you can't convert your STL-files to such images, you must look for other means of analysis.